# How to represent a decimal number in ternary or base $3$ number system?

Tags: number-systems

I need to convert a decimal number into base $3$ number.

$47_{10} ~~\mbox{is}~~ 1202_{3}$.

But how do you represent a negative number in base $3$ notation like $-297$?

please include a example

Comment: Prefix it with a minus sign? $-102000_3$?

Comment: A similar question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189596/negative-decimal-to-other-base-conversion

Answer (score 2):

Just put a minus sign in front of it. By definition, in base 10 $47 + (-47) = 0$; therefore, $1202_3 + (-1202_3) = 0$ and so $-47_{10}$ is $-1202_3$.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use 2's compliment and 3's complement which are 2 other ways to represent positive or negative in base 3.

2's compliment base 3 is like 1's compliment in binary and 3's compliment in base 3 is like 2's compliment in binary.